# JQuery ajax form submit resets select value and does not persist it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've got a select field that I am using to filter results on a table. When I pick an option from the select it fires the ajax and updates the table... however, it resets the select once the table has updated. If I use a text box to filter I don't run into this issue.

form:

```
<%= form_tag items_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form search-form", remote: true do %>
  <%= select_tag :search, options_from_collection_for_select(Model.all, "id", "id"), include_blank: true, class: "form-control", id: "filter-key" %>
<% end %>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("change", "#filter-key", function(){
    var form = $('.search-form');
    $.get(form.action, form.serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't see anything there that would reset the select. Maybe something in the script that's being returned is doing it?

Comment: I'll check the response. I think it has to be something like that.                          I thought it might be a browser issue, but it does the same in all. So something in my setup is wrong.

Comment: `form.action` should be either `form[0].action` or `form.attr('action')`, since `form` is a jQuery object, but `action` is a DOM property.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the script that's being returned must be resetting the select value. You could save the value and put it back in your AJAX code.

```
var self = $(this);
var oldValue = self.val();
$.getScript(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function() {
    self.val(oldValue);
});
```

Comment: @barmer the issue turned out to be where I placed the form. It was inside the partial that was being re-rendered once the ajax was completed. I took a look per your suggestion to check my response content and that was a dead give away.